# Can I know if my answer is correct please?

Tags: vectors

Two vectors **a** and **b** are given. 
 **a** = <2,5,3> and **b** = <4,-2,-1>
 (a) Find a vector perpendicular to both **a** and **b**.
My answer is <1,14,-24> 
(b) Find a unit vector perpendicular to both **a** and **b**. 
My answer is <1/sqrt773, 14/sqrt773, -24/sqrt773>

Comment: Take the dot product of your vector with $a$ and $b$, and see if each is zero. Then take the dot product of your vector with itself, and see if it is one.

Comment: By the way, write $\$$\langle$\ldots$\rangle$\$$ to generate $\langle\ldots \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct as you can directly check

$$(2,5,3)(1,14,-24)=2+70-72=0$$

$$(4,-2,-1)(1,14,-24)=4-28+24=0$$

and also the coefficient to normalize is correct indeed

$$1^2+14^2+24^2=773$$